# Retrieve data from multiple related table in laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have 3 related models.
1.User

```
public function book(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }
```

2.Book

```
public function photo(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Books_photo');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

3.Books_photo

```
public function book(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Book');
    }
```

The relations are

> User hasmany Book

and

> Book hasmany Books_photo

So I want to get all the books with their photo of a particular user.

I can get all the books of a user.I'm using this approach

```
$User = User::with('book')->find(decrypt($request->id));
```

But this returns only the data in book and user table. How can i fetch the photos too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). You will want to do this:

```
$User = User::with('book', 'book.photo')->find(decrypt($request->id));
```

The `book.photo` is a nested eager load that will tell eloquent to get the `photo` relation from the `book` model.